# GET Project Roles returns all roles from the account

Tags: autodesk-bim360

when using https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-industry_roles-GET/
I seem to get all roles from the account, not just project specific roles.
I tested by using a project ID of a project that has no roles, but I still get all the roles created in account admin. I'm using 2leg auth.
Any ideas on how to get only project specific roles? Thanks.

Comment: I can repro.  Since I don't see the definition of roles in project admin, and there is no get account roles, I wonder if this meant for account roles. I'm checking with the product team for clarification.  I will get back to you when I hear from them.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, I have access to 2 accounts, I also get roles from both accounts in same API call. Looking forward to hear how to get account specific roles, or if indeed we have a bug.

Comment: Janne - that sounds strange.  Are you saying that you get a list of roles from the account you did not specify in the endpoint as url parameter?  Could you double check by isolating the API, such as using a tool like Postman?

Comment: No, sorry my mistake. But what I do get are Roles that I cannot see in account admin.

Comment: `code` "id": "c420001a-4c24-4745-99f7-d2f67c84a98f",
        "project_id": "9c2e2c96-adb8-4dcd-a55b-bbd68880c896",
        "name": "Test Role",
        "services": {
     ...............
            },
            "document_management": {
                "access_level": "user"
            }
        },
        "member_group_id": "59311167" `code` this Role has been deleted from account admin and it's still present in the response.

Comment: Janne - I can repro this one, too; after I delete a role, I can still see it in the response. But I do not see a way to distinguish if a role is deleted :-(  I will log an enhancement wish.

Comment: to make it easier to track - I'm putting a change request id here:  
"ACSADMIN-1646:  API - GET Project Roles returns all roles from the account" 
(separate from the access to enhanced roles API access ACSADMIN-531 (was HQ-4095)).